# Find the minimal polynomial of T for each linear map T on V

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> Find the minimal polynomial of T for each linear map T on V. 
>   $V-P_2(R)$ and $T(f(x))=-x f''(x)+f'(x)+2 f(x)$

I find the minimal polynomial to be $(t-2)^3$ by finding the characteristic polynomial. But I was told this should be $(t-2)^2$. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$T=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&1&2\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus
$$T-2I=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\ne\bf0$$
But $(T-2I)^2=\bf0$, so the minimal polynomial is $(t-2)^2$ and not $(t-2)^3$.

Comment: is that by Cayley-Hamilton?

Comment: @spruce No, this is by definition of the minimal polynomial. The characteristic polynomial must be a multiple of the minimal polynomial.